# Possible to search all topics data in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, elastic-stack, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I need a solution preferably something inbuilt (rather than creating my own application) which would help management search through multiple/all topics in Kafka. We are using Confluent Platform. Basically user should be able to search a keyword in a UI and it should search current log of multiple/all Kafka topics and return the data. All the topics in our environment use json to communicate.

So this search would enable us to track flow for example, multiple microservices send data from one system to another system and this flow can be tracked via a correlation id which is present in all the jsons. So if someone searchers this correlation id he should be able to see the messages involved in the flow. This search would have more use cases later on.

We need a solution which would have minimal coding involved. We would prefer to use a UI like Kibana.

On basic reading I suspect below solutions but not really sure as I am new to Confluent (used open-source Apache Kafka earlier):
Sol 1: use ksqldb. (need more help on how to use it)
Sol 2: Stream all topics data using Kafka Connect to Elastic Search by using inbuilt plugin and use Kibana on top of Elastic.

Kindly help to find the best case alternative.

Comment: Option 2 is *probably* what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Elastic, sure.

You could also use Splunk, though.

There is also the `pdk` tool offered by [Pilosa](https://www.pilosa.com/docs/latest/introduction/) that creates a distributed index over Kafka events. (no affiliation)

Another option would be [distributed tracing](https://www.confluent.io/blog/importance-of-distributed-tracing-for-apache-kafka-based-applications/) using interceptors between *clients*, not "on all topics", which sounds like what you actually need